# How to skip a loop after a certain count to the next loop and back again after a certain count is achieved in the next loop

Tags: laravel, loops

From the code below, it works just fine but now I'd like to achieve a functionality whereby when the first loop iterates 3 times it breaks then the second loop iterates 3 times and then breaks. And the process starts again from the first loop and repeats again and again.

Blade:

```php
@foreach ($officialOutfits as $outfit)
    {{ $outfit }}
@endforeach
    
@foreach ($casuallOutfits as $outfit)
    {{ $outfit }}
@endforeach
```

Route

```php
Route::get('/products', function () {
    $outfits = Outfit::latest()->get();
    $officialOutfits = Outfit::where('look', 'official')->latest()->get();
    $casualOutfits = Outfit::where('look', 'casual')->get();
        
    return view('products', compact(['casualOutfits', 'officialOutfits']));
})->name('products');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [**`DOCUMENTATION`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) states, you can use the `$loop` variable when on Blade.

So you should have something like this:

```php
@foreach ($officialOutfits as $outfit)
    @if ($loop->index >= 3)
        @break
    @endif

    {{ $outfit }}
@endforeach

@foreach ($casuallOutfits as $outfit)
    @if ($loop->index >= 3)
        @break
    @endif

    {{ $outfit }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This will indeed break the first loop after 3 iterations then proceed tho next loop. After 3 iterations the second loop will also break and then all the loops will stop. What I'm trying to achieve: After the second loop breaks then the first loop iterates again from the 3rd index this time round.

Comment: You cannot achieve that, you have no way to say "start from the 4th item and iterate 3 times" to the `foreach`... You could try consuming the data and deleting it from the main varibale inmidiately, but that will still be ugly and it is super wierd what you are trying to do. Why do you need to do this ?

Comment: A product in my outfits table has either a category of casual or official. When displaying them, I'd like the first row with 3 products to have items with the category "casual" while the second row with the category "official" and the third row with the category " casual" and so on and so forth. So, after every row which has 3 products the category alternates. I thought of solving it with the above way but may be I'm approaching it wrongly... I'm a leaner by the way.

Answer (score -1):

You set the for loop to only loop three times, that's standard. What you also need is **recursion.** Recursion is making a function call itself:

```
function doStuff(){
   forloop{
      forloop2{
          
      }
    }
   doStuff();
}
```

This will go on infinitely if you don't terminate it, so you can set the limit to whatever you want - say, 50 times.

```
let limit = 0;
while (limit < 50){
    function doStuff(){
       forloop{
          forloop2{
              
          }
        }
       limit++
       doStuff();
    }
}
```